# What does "sanctified" mean in John 10:36?

Tags: greek, john, historical-interpretation, authorial-intent

John 10:36 KJB "Say ye of him, whom the Father hath sanctified, and sent into the world, Thou blasphemest; because I said, I am the Son of God?"

In this verse what is Jesus being sanctified to:

1. An office. In which case which one?
2. A task, the ability to do that task or both?
3. In what ways might the Father's sanctification of the Son overlap with Jeremiah being sanctified in Jeremiah 1:5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does "sanctified" mean in [John 10:36]?**

1. **Holy.** - "Qodesh" (קֹ֖דֶשׁ) in the Tanakh (Hebrew Bible) when referencing humans "set apart" for God describes the Priest [Exodus 28:36-37] & Prophet [Jeremiah 35:1].

In reference to a Prophet ( Navii, נָבִ֥יא ) - **Jeremiah 1:5 [MT] "5When I had not yet formed you in the womb, I knew you, and when you had not yet emerged from the womb, **I appointed you**; a prophet to the nations I made you." (בְּטֶ֨רֶם אֶצָּרְךָ֚ (כתיב אֶצָּורְךָ֚) בַבֶּ֙טֶן֙ יְדַעְתִּ֔יךָ וּבְטֶ֛רֶם תֵּצֵ֥א מֵרֶ֖חֶם הִקְדַּשְׁתִּ֑יךָ נָבִ֥יא לַגּוֹיִ֖ם נְתַתִּֽיךָ)

**"I Appointed you"** ( Hi-Qadosh-Ti-Kha, **הִקְדַּשְׁתִּ֑יךָ** ) = "I Sanctified you".

In reference to a Priest - **Exodus 28:36 [MT]** "36And you shall make a showplate of pure gold, and you shall engrave upon it like the engraving of a seal: **Holy** to the Lord." (וְעָשִׂ֥יתָ צּיץ זָהָ֣ב טָה֑וֹר וּפִתַּחְתָּ֤ עָלָיו֙ פִּתּוּחֵ֣י חֹתָ֔ם קֹ֖דֶשׁ לַֽיהֹוָֽה)

"**Holy** to YHVH" (**Qodesh** La-YHVH, קֹ֖דֶשׁ לַֽיהֹוָֽה)

> **Hegiasen** (ἡγίασεν) in the Greek Gospel of [John 10:36] is translated as "sanctified" in reference to a Holy Son. **Hagiazon** (ἁγιάζον) in the Greek Gospel of [Matthew 23:19] is translated as "sanctifies" in reference to a Holy Offering. **Hagiasas** (ἁγιάσας) in the Greek Gospel of [Matthew 23:17] is translated as "having sanctified" in reference to Holy Items.

Something **Sanctified** is Holy, used only for serving God.

**John 10:36 [KJV]**

> "Say ye of him, whom the Father hath sanctified, and sent into the world, Thou blasphemest; because I said, I am the Son of God?"

What was the Meaning of "Sanctified" in [John 10:36] from other Commentaries?

**Holy**

> Methodist Trinitarian - John Wesley's Commentary on [John 10:36] : "Say ye of him whom the Father hath sanctified, and sent into the world - This sanctification (whereby he is essentially the **Holy** One of God) is mentioned as prior to his mission, and together with it implies, Christ was God in the highest sense, infinitely superior to that wherein those judges were so called." [https://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/wesleys-explanatory-notes/john/john-10.html]

**Set Apart**

> Presbyterian Trinitarian - Matthew Poole's Commentary on [John 10:36] : "Suppose I were no more than a mere man, yet being sanctified, that is, **set apart** of God for the special work of man’s redemption, and sent of God into the world with commission both to reveal and to do his will, yet dare you say that I blaspheme" [https://biblehub.com/commentaries/john/10-36.htm ].

Answer (score 3):

The verb ἁγιάζω (hagiazó), variously translated "sanctify", "make holy", "hallow", "consecrate", etc, has the primary meaning, "to set apart for a special duty".  (See BDAG and Thayer)

Thus, when something or someone is set apart, it or they are ***dedicated*** to a special duty in contradistinction from other things or persons.

In the case of John 10:36, referring to Jesus as the Son of God, we are told that Jesus was "sanctified" or "dedicated" or "consecrated" and sent into the world.  Thus, the force of this statement is that Jesus had been set aside for the special and exalted task of being incarnated and coming into the world.  See Phil 2:5-11.

The cognate adjective is used in Luke 1:35 to describe Jesus before He was born, "So the **holy** one to be born will be called the Son of God."

There is a clear allusion in John 10:36 to Jesus' pre-existence (before His incarnation, see also John 17:5, 24) as being selected to be set apart and dedicated to the task of incarnation as Messiah.

All people who fulfilled special offices, (prophets and priests are prime examples) in the OT were thus sanctified for their task as the example of Jer 1:5 suggests.  many other things are also sanctified in the OT such as:

- Num 7:1 - the tabernacle and its furnishings; see also Ex 29:43, 2 Chron 30:8, etc
- Neh 3:1 - the sheep gate in Jerusalem
- 2 Chron 5:11 - the priests for the task of ministration; see also Eze 48:11
- 2 Chron 30:17 - the congregation for the task of worship
- Num 18:17 - the firstborn in Israel as family priests
- 1 Sam 7:1 - Eleazar to care for the ark of the Covenant
- Num 20:13 - The LORD in the eyes of the Israelites

... and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

**What does “sanctified” mean in John 10:36?**

Definition from Google

What it means to be sanctified?

"To make holy; set apart as sacred; consecrate. to purify or free from sin: Sanctify your hearts. to impart religious sanction to; render legitimate or binding: to sanctify a vow. to entitle to reverence or respect. to make productive of or conducive to spiritual blessing."

To get a better understanding of the word "sanctified" we will also consider some usages of the word in the scriptures.

God  commanded Moses to say to the complaining Israelites:

Numbers 11:18  NET

> 18 “And say to the people, ‘Sanctify yourselves for tomorrow, and you
> will eat meat, for you have wept in the hearing[b] of the Lord,
> saying, “Who will give us meat to eat, for life[d] was good for us in
> Egypt?” Therefore the Lord will give you meat, and you will eat.

Before Israel crossed the Jordan River, Joshua ordered:

Joshua 3:5  King James Version

> 5 And Joshua said unto the people, Sanctify yourselves: for tomorrow
> the Lord will do wonders among you.

Exodus 19:10-11   King James Version

> 10 And the Lord said unto Moses, Go unto the people, and sanctify them
> today and tomorrow, and let them wash their clothes,  11 And be ready
> against the third day: for the third day the Lord will come down in
> the sight of all the people upon mount Sinai.

Matthew 6:9 Darby Bible Translation

> Thus, therefore, pray ye: Our Father who art in the heavens, **let thy
> name be sanctified**

Matthew 6:9   International Standard Version

> Therefore, this is how you should pray: 'Our Father in heaven, may
> **your name be kept holy.**

In all cases it denotes being  morally and spiritually clean, purifies, set apart, make holy, including   physical cleanliness, in other words staying away from anything that displeases God

In Jesus' case, God selected his only-begotten Son and sent him to earth to do special work on behalf of God’s name and to give his life as a ransom for humankind. But he was not received and respected by the Jewish nation as that sent one; rather, they denied his sonship and his position with his Father. He replied to them:

John 10:36  NET

> 36 Do you say about the one whom the Father set apart and sent into
> the world, ‘You are blaspheming,’ because I said, **‘I am the Son of
> God’?**

John 10:36  NASB

> 36 Do you say of Him, whom the Father sanctified and sent into the
> world, ‘You are blaspheming,’ because I said, **‘I am the Son of God’?**

Jeremiah

Jeremiah 1:5 tn Heb “I knew you.” The parallelism here with “set you apart” and “appointed you” make clear that Jeremiah is speaking of his foreordination to be a prophet.  (from NET footnotes)

Jeremiah 1:4-5 NET

Jeremiah’s Call and Commission

> 4 The Lord’s message came to me, 5 “Before I formed you in your
> mother’s womb[a] I chose you.[b]  Before you were born I set you
> apart. I appointed you to be a prophet to the nations.”

God, intervening by a miracle or by a guiding providence, that they might be his special servants. Among these men are Isaac, Samson, Samuel, John the Baptizer, and Jesus.​

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of sanctify is "to make holy," specifically by setting something apart as holy (consecrate) to make someone free from sin. The Gospel teaches us that Jesus was "sanctified" by God before being sent in to the world. This is part of Jesus' repudiation of his oppossers of their false charge of blasphemy. If, as trinitarians, binitarians and  Jesus' enemies claim that Jesus made himself God, then this statement of Jesus "**whom the Father sanctified and sent into the world**" does not make sense. (There are two Gods if Jesus is God too.) God does not need to be made holy or be consecrated". **The chief priests and the Sanhhedrin knew he was a man and not God**. The Plot to Kill Jesus (Matthew 26:1-5; Mark 14:1-2; Luke 22:1-6)

Matthew 22:15  YLT also says, Then the Pharisees having gone, took counsel how they might ensnare him in words.

John 11:45-57 ASV says

45Many therefore of the Jews, who came to Mary and beheld that which he did, believed on him. 46But some of them went away to the Pharisees, and told them the things which Jesus had done.

47The **chief priests** therefore and the **Pharisees** gathered a council, and said, What do we? for **this man doeth many signs**. 48If we let him thus alone, all men will believe on him: and the Romans will come and take away both our place and our nation. 49But a certain one of them, **Caiaphas**, being high priest that year, **said unto them**, Ye know nothing at all, 5**0nor do ye take account that it is expedient for you that one man should die for the people**, and that the whole nation perish not. 51Now this he said not of himself: but, being high priest that year, he prophesied that Jesus should die for the nation; 52and not for the nation only, but that he might also gather together into one the children of God that are scattered abroad. 53So from that day forth they took counsel that they might put him to death.

54Jesus therefore walked no more openly among the Jews, but departed thence into the country near to the wilderness, into a city called Ephraim; and there he tarried with the disciples.

55Now the passover of the Jews was at hand: and many went up to Jerusalem out of the country before the passover, to purify themselves. 56They sought therefore for Jesus, and spake one with another, as they stood in the temple, What think ye? That he will not come to the feast? 57Now the chief priests and the Pharisees had given commandment, that, if any man knew where he was, he should show it, that they might take him.

This is substantiated by the fact that nobody asked Jesus if he is God during his trial. Jesus was tried for claiming to be the king of the Jews. Mark 15:2. **Pilate knew it was out of envy that the pharisees wanted Jesus dead.** Mark 15:10 and Matthew 27:18 YLT